# Calculate time difference in same column based on couple filters PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, measure

Good day,

I'm looking for a measure that will calculate the time difference based on certain filters.
The measure I'm looking is for example, I would like to calculate the time needed for a vessel port call (unique "number") column from "Fieldname" = "Pilot On Board inwards" to "Fieldname" = "All Fast" in hours. I would like to have the first Pilot on boards inwards to first All Fast.

I can the reuse the same measure to calculate other duration for the same port call.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nT16d.png)

[Example data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jLWQ.png)

| Number | Port | Ship | Trip | FieldName | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | End of sea passage | 18/09/2022 15:45 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Anchored | 18/09/2022 16:30 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | NOR tendered | 18/09/2022 16:30 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Pilot on board inwards | 19/09/2022 03:55 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Anchor aweigh | 21/09/2022 02:40 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | First line ashore | 21/09/2022 13:20 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | All fast | 21/09/2022 13:30 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Tanks accepted/passed | 21/09/2022 14:15 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | NOR accepted | 21/09/2022 14:25 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Hose connected | 21/09/2022 17:00 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Cargo loading | 21/09/2022 17:15 | 22/09/2022 00:36 |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Hose disconnected | 22/09/2022 02:40 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Hose connected | 22/09/2022 02:50 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Cargo loading 22/09/2022 03:47 | 22/09/2022 14:48 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Cargo loading 22/09/2022 15:42 | 22/09/2022 17:30 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Hose disconnected | 22/09/2022 20:36 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Cargo docs on board | 22/09/2022 21:48 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Left berth | 23/09/2022 09:12 |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Pilot on board |  |  |
| 1 | Antwerpen | S | 22017 | Surveyor on board |  |  |

Kind regards,

Comment: Please post sample data as copiable text.

Comment: Have added sample data as copiable text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following calculated column should work.

[image]

```
Column = 
IF(
    'Table'[FieldName] = "All fast",
    VAR d = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[FromDate]), ALLEXCEPT('Table',  'Table'[Number]), 'Table'[FieldName] = "Pilot on board inwards")
    RETURN 
        DATEDIFF( d,'Table'[FromDate], HOUR)
)
```

**EDIT**
New measure:

```
Column = 
IF(
    'Table'[FieldName] = "All fast"  && CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[FromDate]),ALLEXCEPT('Table',  'Table'[Number]), 'Table'[FieldName] = "All fast") = 'Table'[FromDate] ,
    VAR d = CALCULATE(MIN('Table'[FromDate]), ALLEXCEPT('Table',  'Table'[Number]), 'Table'[FieldName] = "Pilot on board inwards")
    RETURN 
        DATEDIFF( d,'Table'[FromDate], HOUR)
)
```

Comment: Perfect that's it, however I now noticed that some calls have multiple All Fast times, is there a way I can only calculate the first All Fast against first Pilot on Board inwards? If I calculate against all "All Fast" it skews my average as I'm only interested in the fist All Fast against first Pilot on board inwards"

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Great, thank you very much! For my PowerBI knowledge, could I do the same with a measure? (same formula)